# put buttons at bottom right of material-ui dialog

Tags: css, material-ui

I've got some quite nice react hooks based state management that implements a multi-step form inside a material-ui dialog.

I want the dialog to stay the same size and I want the back/forward buttons that take the user through the steps to stay in the same place even though the size and number of the input elements are slightly different from step to step.

I've managed to force the dialog to a fixed viewport % but bottom/right aligning the buttons is defeating me.

Any ideas?

I found a great example similar to my requirement: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/docs/src/pages/getting-started/templates/checkout

I want something like this but I want a UX which is more stable. The example has variable height. I'd like to fix the height to the height of the maximum height tab/step and then I'd like the next/back/submit buttons to be in the same place on each tab/step, so, for example you can click next to step through without moving the mouse.

Comment: Can you add your code to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: I'll try and build something small enough to share but I'm really looking for some general guidance from someone who understands layout.

Comment: I'm sure it should be possible to combine fixed height with 'flex-end'.